Databricks SQL analysis of Powerbi Metadata
From Databricks SQL query history , we get what query is coming from source = Powerbi.
How to know metadata here like what is the workspace id or what is the dataset id.
We tried to fetch the query history using API (but most information is missing)
url = f"{DATABRICKS_INSTANCE}/api/2.0/sql/history/queries" headers = { "Authorization": f"Bearer {TOKEN}", "Content-Type": "application/json" } all_queries = [] next_page_token = None while True: params = {} if next_page_token: params['page_token'] = next_page_token

You cannot get the workspace id and dataset details in query history api.
Because whenever you build report by filtering and select fields, it makes a request every time to /sql/1.0/warehouses http path or endpoint passing query and credential only.
And only those information will be saved and gives you the results through query history api.
You can get workspace id using powerbi rest api with some filters.
Using the results of query history api you filter out the queries belong to PowerBI as Source.
and using User, Run as you filter out the workspaces where these users belong to.
Here, is the sample url with expand and filter.
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups?$expand=users&$filter=users/any(u: u/emailAddress eq 'jaya@xxx.com')

Here, you pass the email of the user or who ran the query.
